# How should I make the struct to get this JSON data in SwiftUI?

Tags: json, swift, struct, swiftui

I am making an HTTP GET request and I want to save the JSON response that looks like this:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "success",
    "patients": [
        {
            "_id": "5e77c7bbc7cbd30024f3eadb",
            "name": "Bogdan Patient",
            "username": "bogdanp",
            "phone": "0732958473"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e77c982a2736a0024e895fa",
            "name": "Robert Patient",
            "username": "robertp",
            "phone": "0739284756"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my struct:

```
struct Doctor: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  let patients: [Patients]
}

struct Patients: Codable {
  let id: String
  let name: String
  let phone: String
}
```

Comment: You have to add CodingKeys in both structs to skip `id` in `Doctor` and to map `_id` in `Patients`.

Comment: And how do I do that? Can you post it in an answer? I am not familiar with CodingKeys.

Comment: Then you should do some research, maybe read this [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) from Apple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your model, `id` is expected in the JSON whereas the keyname in the JSON is `_id`.
You can use `CodingKeys` to fix this:

```
struct Patients: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let phone: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case name
        case phone
    }
}
```

`CodingKeys` creates a map between the keynames in your model and the keynames in the JSON response.
There are other reasons to use `CodingKeys` but for your current purpose this is enough.

Read More: [Codable in Swift](https://medium.com/@sarunw/codable-in-swift-4-0-1a12e38599d8)